# Результат async/await

Tags: c#, async-await

Пытаюсь разобраться с асинхронным выполнением кода. Взял пример [из MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh191443.aspx) и немного упростил:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = await emuAccessTheWebAsync();
    label1.Text += i.ToString();
}

async Task<int> emuAccessTheWebAsync()
{
    Task<string> t = new Task<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return "completed"; });
    DoIndependentWork();
    string urlContents = await t;
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Спустя 3 секунды, как указано внутри таска, ничего не происходит.
Пробовал выводить результат внутри таска, но при доступе к `label1` получаю, разумеется, cross-thread exception.

Как все-таки правильно вытащить результат из асинхроного метода? И можно ли из него передавать в основной поток какие-то промежуточные результаты?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы создаёте таск вручную, но не запускаете его. Поэтому `await t` никогда не дождётся.

Правильно считается создавать «горячий», уже запущенный и бегущий `Task`:

```
Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return "completed"; });
```

Ещё лучшим вариантом является не выполнять `Task` в отдельном потоке, и использовать неблокирующее ожидание:

```
Task<string> t = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(3000); return "completed"; });
```

или например

```
async Task Temp()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "completed";
}

async Task<int> emuAccessTheWebAsync()
{
    Task<string> t = Temp();
    DoIndependentWork();
    string urlContents = await t;
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Comment: неблокирующее ожидание? что это и чем лучше в одном async завернуть его еще раз?

Comment: @kvvk: Не блокирует поток на время ожидания. В большом приложении это может быть важно, если потоки — расходуемый ресурс. Ну и скорее же, не нужно новый поток создавать.

Comment: а разве само выражение Task.Run(...) по сути своей не создает отдельный поток? И как оно может параллельно чего-то ждать если не в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @kvvk: `Task.Run` выполняет на thread pool'е. А ждать очень просто: у вас есть объект в памяти, который не выполняется, и подписан на какой-то event. По приходу event'а он продолжает выполнение кода.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте

```
    static async Task<int> emuAccessTheWebAsync()
        {
            Task<string> t = new Task<string>(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return "completed"; });
//запуск
            t.Start();
            string urlContents = await t;
            return urlContents.Length;
        }
```